# Modify VBScript to stop excel dialog boxes from appearing

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to use a vbscript to open an excel spreadsheet, run a macro, and save the sheet for a daily inventory update.  I found the following code here and it is working fine for me, but i want it to run automatically without throwing up a prompts that I'm getting: "This will cancel a pending data refresh" (related to the macro I'm guessing)

I can't seem to find the right code to get this to happen.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the existing vbscript:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'~~> Change Path here
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\testfiles\Daily Update.xlsm", 0, False)

xlApp.Run "RefreshData"
xlBook.Close(False)
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Daily Update Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

and here is the Excel Macro:

```
Sub RefreshData()
'
' RefreshData Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O
'
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Would `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False` help?

Comment: A google search would have uncovered the answer as the first result...

Comment: Thanks ASH, that worked.  I did try several google searches, but I probably didn't know the proper terminology to get the right result.  So thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`xlapp.displayalerts = false` in the vbscript OR `application.displayalerts = false` in the module will suppress the alerts.

Make sure you set it back to true at the end of the code.